# Iteration of a map in groovy prints null

Tags: csv, dictionary, groovy, iteration

***Why the Map obtained from the large csv file prints null values while iteration like shown below:***

```
@Grab('com.xlson.groovycsv:groovycsv:1.1')
import static com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser.parseCsv 
import com.sun.rowset.internal.Row 

def csv="srcev.csv" 
def df = new FileReader(csv) 
def data = parseCsv(df, readFirstLine: true) 

def csvMap1 = [:]
int j=0;

for (def row : data) {
    csvMap1[row.values[0]] = row.values[1]
    j++;
}

for (i=0;i<=j;i++) {
    println csvMap1.keySet().value[i]
}
```

**Output:**

```
value1
value2
null
null
null
.
.
.
```

Up to the End of the csv, It prints null but really csv has another values.

**Note:** This iteration only affects the large files. For small csv files it works well.

Comment: could you please provide an example of cvs file?

Comment: @daggett In my csv, around 8000 rows there. You can assume it should be like value1,value2,....,value8000.

Comment: What's `csvMap1.keySet().value[i]`?

Comment: @tim_yates csvMap1.keySet() means the first column which loaded in code as `csvMap1[row.values[0]]`.  So the  `csvMap1.keySet().value[i]` means i th value of the first column.

Comment: @daggett Sorry for my unclear response. Don't care about the second column [1]. I am accessing only the first column means the `csvMap1.keySet().value[i]` or `csvMap1[row.values[0]]`

Comment: I created a file with 10000 lines like `value1,two,three` and tested your script and it works perfectly fine like you would expect, except that _one_ `null` is printed in the end because you should have used `i<j`, not `i<=j`. Actually, as you are in Groovy, I'd replace all from `def csvMap1 = [:]` until the end by the one line `data.collect { it.values.first() }.each { println it }`. Same result, better readable, more Groovy-style. ;-)

Comment: Actually all from `def df ...` until the end with `new File(csv).withReader { def data = parseCsv(it, readFirstLine: true); data.collect { it.values.first() }.each { println it } }` to also ensure the stream is properly closed after usage.

Comment: @Vampire Thanks for your kind response and involvement. I already executed your approach before this . but i want to continue this with map [:] for further process. Some how i managed to continue this. :D